# Selenium not clicking Search button with no id?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

[ErrorPart2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uc7au.jpg) [Error Part1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpWrD.jpg)I am trying to click a button with no id in inspect. I am using Python and Selenium. I am trying to use the button's Class, but the Search button does not get clicked. I am not sure what other solution to use. I have looked at other similar questions on this forum but their solution did not work for me.
The site is nerdwallet.com. And the button is the Green Search button. I have attached the image.
Please let me know what solution to use. Thank you. Cheers[Nerdwallet Search Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IPrd.jpg)

```
import webbrowser
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
  
options= Options()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

web=webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),options=options)

web.get('https://www.nerdwallet.com/?trk=nw_gn_5.0')
  
Name="credit card"

cl=web.find_element("xpath",'//*[@id="global-nav"]/div[2]/div[1]/button')
cl.click()

find=web.find_element("xpath",'//*[@id="searchInput"]')

find.send_keys(Name)

bu=web.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "_1_LcAp _2nYXVh _1J48pr")

bu.click()
```

Comment: The error code is not from this code.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the class of the button just to "._1_LcAp" so the line becomes

```
bu=web.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "._1_LcAp")
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried your solution but it still gives me the same error and does not click the Search button. Cheers

Comment: which error arose?

Comment: Thanks. Please see the two new images I attached with my question. The error is too long to capture in one image. Thanks

Comment: what does this line mean"  
futm_medium=cpc&futm_source=google&futm_campaign=183513080~12071138480&futm_term=finder~e~g~kwd-36367991&futm_content=~~EAIaIQobChMI_6XorNur_QIVLZlmAh3HLQVtEAAYASAAEgIc6fD_BwE&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI_6XorNur_QIVLZlmAh3HLQVtEAAYASAAEgIc6fD_BwE'"?

Comment: Sorry, not sure where that line came from. It is not in my code which I am running. I have deleted it from the question. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: the certification thing is still an error or has it disappeared after the line deletion?

Comment: It is still an error. The line was not in the code I was running. The line was only in the code I included in the question over here :)